# array don't Access in the template

Tags: django

I want to known the number of views in each separately Playlist where I can store the view number for each one in the array and later display it in the template but show me the array in the following in the template:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here the array is ​​repeated with Playlists and I can not move between the elements of the array

Issue 2: I can not determine the number of views per person

```
def playlist_view(request,id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,pk=id)
    playlists = Playlist.objects.filter(category=category)

    views=list()
    for playlist in playlists:
        views.append(PlaylistView.objects.filter(playlist=playlist).count())
    print(views)

    return render(request, 'playlist.html',{'category': category,'playlists': playlists,'views':views})
```

```
                    {% for playlist in playlists %}
                    {{ views }} :: {{ playlist.name }}

                        {% endfor %}
```

```
def track_view(request,id_category,id_playlist):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=id_category)
    playlist= get_object_or_404(Playlist,pk=id_playlist)

    if not PlaylistView.objects.filter(playlist=playlist, session=request.session.session_key):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        view = PlaylistView(playlist=playlist, ip=ip, created_dt=datetime.now(), session=request.session.session_key)
        view.save()
```

here is right access in the Array element But not access in same time playlists

```
      {% for view in views %}
                    {{ view }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for playlist in playlists %}
              {{ views }} :: {{ playlist.name }}
      {% endfor %}
```

how to access in two Array in the same loop

Answer (score 0):

As I see you want views of every playlist with it,
In This case you can use setattr() function for setting views count to playlist object. But better approach for this is making a query like this

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

Playlist.objects.filter(category=category).annotate(view_count= Count('related_name'))
```

note: related name should be from PlaylistView foreign key field with Playlist.
Than you can access like this -

```
for playlist in playlists:
    {{ playlist.view_count }} :: {{ playlist.name }}
```

For playlistview for each playlist you can write a query like this:

```
playlist = Playlist.objects.filter(category=category).prefetch_related(Prefetch('related_name', PlaylistView.objects.all(), 'my_list'))
```

and than you can access that queryset like:

```
for playlist in playlists:
        {{ playlist.view_count }} :: {{ playlist.name }}
        for view in playlist.my_list:
            {{view}}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for response but Each Category has many Playlist and every Playlist has many PlaylistView.

I've successfully stored PlaylistView for every Playlist:

```
def track_view(request,id_category,id_playlist):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=id_category)
    playlist= get_object_or_404(Playlist,pk=id_playlist)

    if not PlaylistView.objects.filter(playlist=playlist, session=request.session.session_key):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        view = PlaylistView(playlist=playlist, ip=ip, created_dt=datetime.now(), session=request.session.session_key)
        view.save()
```

How to know PlaylistView for each Playlist here(on the other page):

```
def playlist_view(request,id):
    category=get_object_or_404(Category,pk=id)
    playlists=Playlist.objects.filter(category=category)

    for playlist in playlists:
        PlaylistView.objects.filter(playlist=playlist).annotate(view_count=Count('playlistviews'))
```

And Thanks for agian!